# Intuition for Inclusion-Exclusion Principle

Tags: combinatorics, intuition, inclusion-exclusion

Many of us are familiar with the [inclusion-exclusion principle](http://www.saylor.org/site/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/MA111_Wikipedia_Inclusion-Exclusion-Principle_6.8.2012.pdf). I think the principle makes total sense when applied to the two or three sets and we have the following:

$|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|-|A\cap B|$

$|A\cup B\cup C|=|A|+|B|+|C|-|A\cap B|-|A\cap C|-|B\cap C|+|A \cap B \cap C|\text{.}$

However, it is not as easy to understand how this works in the general case. In lieu of a rigorous proof, it is easy to see that the IEP rests on the following principle: suppose that $x$ is a member of $n$ sets. Then $x$ gets counted $n$ times on the first count, subtracted $n$ choose $2$ times on the second count, added back in $n$ choose $3$ times on the third count, *etc*. In other words:

$${n \choose 1}-{n\choose 2}+{n\choose 3}-{n\choose 4}+\cdots+(-1)^{n+1}{n \choose n}=1$$

Or, perhaps more appropriately written as

$${n\choose 0}-{n \choose 1}+{n\choose 2}+\cdots+(-1)^{n}{n \choose n}=0$$

I should clarify that the proof of this is easy to do *algebraically*, but I am looking for a useful *intuitive* explanation of the above property, and I'm curious how people view the IEP from a combinatorial perspective.

Comment: have you seen a bijective proof for exclusion inclusion, you can find it in Stnaley's enumerative combinatorics 1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> One essential aspect of the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle (IEP) is the transformation of *at least* information to *exact* information.
>
> - If counting objects having *at least* a number of properties is simple, but counting objects having *exactly* a number of properties is difficult, than the IEP comes into play.
> - The  *objects* are represented by the elements contained in $A_1,\dots,A_n$ and the *properties* of an element $x$ are the sets $A_j,1\leq j\leq n$, which contain $x$.

If we have this *essence* of IEP in mind and we look at the expression:

\begin{align*}
\left|\bigcup_{j=1}^{n}A_j\right|=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\left|A_j\right|
-\sum_{1\leq i \leq j \leq n}\left|A_i\cap A_j\right|\pm\cdots+(-1)^{n-1}\left|\bigcap_{j=1}^{n}A_j\right|
\end{align*}

we observe, that the right hand side (RHS) consists of summands with *at least* information.

Note, that the summand

$$\left|A_i\cap A_j\right|\quad \text{in}\quad\sum_{1\leq i \leq j \leq n}\left|A_i\cap A_j\right|$$

is not only the number of elements which are in $A_i$ and $A_j$ it is more precisely the number of elements which are *at least* in $A_i$ and $A_j$, since elements $x$ in $A_i\cap A_j$ may also be contained in other sets of $A_1,\dots,A_n$.

Whereas the LHS
$$\left|\bigcup_{j=1}^{n}A_j\right|$$
  presents the number of elements which are *exactly* in $\bigcup_{j=1}^{n}A_j$.

> We observe the IEP transforms counting information with *at least* properties into counting information with *exact* properties.

**Note:** This intuitive connection between *at least* and *exact* information has a formal represention. Using generating functions you will get a kind of eye-birds view at hand, which transforms the *at least* to an *exact* information as  simple *shift by one* of the argument. For  more information about  this  approach you may have a look at section 4.2 of  H.S. Wilfs [Generatingfunctionology](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf).

Answer (score 8):

The way I usually think of the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle goes something like this:

If something is in $n$ of the $S_j$, it will be counted $\binom{n}{k}$ times in the sum of the sizes of intersections of $k$ of the $S_j$. Therefore, it will be counted
$$
\sum_{k\ge1}(-1)^{k-1}\binom{n}{k}=1\tag{1}
$$
time in the expression
$$
\begin{align}
&\overbrace{\sum_i\left|S_i\right|}^{\binom{n}{1}}-\overbrace{\sum_{i\lt j}\left|S_i\cap S_j\right|}^{\binom{n}{2}}+\overbrace{\sum_{i\lt j\lt k}\left|S_i\cap S_j\cap S_k\right|}^{\binom{n}{3}}-\dots\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
where the expression above each sum is the number of times an object in $n$ of the $S_j$ will be counted in that sum.

Thus, because of $(1)$, any object, no matter how many of the $S_j$ it is in (no matter what $n$ is), will be counted only once in $(2)$.

Comment: Do you mean for your sum to stop at $n$?

Comment: It will since, for $k\gt n$, all of the binomial coefficients are $0$. I have edited the sum to make it less confusing.

Answer (score 0):

In combinatorics, it's well-known that for a non-empty set, the number of non-empty odd subsets is equal to the number of non-empty even subsets plus one:

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor}\binom{n}{2k-1}=1+
\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor}\binom{n}{2k}
$$

**Inclusion and Exclusion**

Let's define an even intersection as an intersection of an even number of sets. An odd intersection is an intersection of an odd number of sets.

Let John sum the number of elements in all possible odd intersections while Mary sum the number of elements in all even intersections. John will count each unique element exactly once more than Mary. Therefore, by subtracting Mary's number from John's number, we get the number of unique elements.